# Is this usage of “luxury of knowing” correct?

Tags: word-usage

I would like to use "luxury of knowing" phrase. I searched for its meaning in internet. It seems that it is used in a song [Lori McKenna – The Luxury of Knowing](http://www.songmeanings.net/songs/view/3530822107858855834/) and a movie [A Few Good Men](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/A_Few_Good_Men)

Lori McKenna Song:

> Turns to ice and your whole world just starts snowing
>       And I don’t have the luxury of knowing

A few Good Men uses following:

> You have the luxury of not knowing what I know:
>       that Santiago's death, while tragic, probably saved lives.

Is following usage is correct in meaning?

> We do not have this luxury of always knowing true answer in XXX domain.

What I mean is sometimes we know an answer, and sometimes we do not, but always knowing an answer in this domain is a privilege or luxury.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would say *the* luxury, not *this* luxury, and I'd put an article before the name of the domain. I'd probably move the word *always* as well:

> We don't always have the luxury of knowing the answer in the XXX domain.

That sounds more natural to me, although it's hard to say for certain without any additional context given.  If I saw the entire paragraph, instead of a solitary sentence, I might alter my answer somewhat.

Incidentally, I thought the expression *true answer* seemed redundant in the original sentence, so I removed the word *true*.

Comment: Agreed - "this luxury" makes it sound like you're talking about some specific luxury, whereas "the luxury of..." is more of an idiomatic phrase.

Comment: Nice answer +1.